# How to fix Adobe Flex simple multiplication error

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

We are using version 3.6. We call a rounding function to clean up the decimal part. Something like this...

```
private function ceilingRounding(value:Number, power:Number):Number
    {
    var scale:Number = Math.pow(10, power);
    return (Math.ceil(value * scale) / scale);
    }
```

The function result is unexpected for the following values:
value = 76.7549, scale = 10000.
The result should be 76.7549 but we get 76.7550

Using the debugger, we see that value * scale = 767549.0000000001. Of course this would be rounded up to 76.7550, but why are we getting .0000000001 and how can we fix this?

Comment: Classic [floating point precision](https://www.google.com/search?q=flickr#q=floating+point+precision) issue. It'll be the same in javascript or even in Java (though in Java you'll have to go many more places after the comma to encounter it).

Comment: I would agree with you if "76.7549 * 1000000 / 100" would result into the same wrong value, but I get "767549" with no trailing error. Also, something like "22252 - 22252.03" gives -0.029999999998835847 instead of -0.3. At this point it seems that no Flex operation (math) can be trusted. So far I had to use GraniteDS BigDecimal to perform basic math operations. I also got the same behavior with Flex 4.6. I do not know about the Apache version.

Comment: About your last point: there will be no difference between versions of Flex; primitives and math operations are a pure Flash/ActionScript matter, Flex is just a framework (that has no BigDecimal equivalent unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

The "NUMBERS" values ​​hold this approximation operation, you can modify your function and add the following into operation, plus I let the function that I use regularly to do the rounding.

```
public static function roundToPrecision(numberVal:Number, precision:int = 0):Number
        {
            var decimalPlaces:Number = Math.pow(10, precision);
            return Math.round(decimalPlaces * numberVal) / decimalPlaces;
        }
```

If you need Fixed decimal Number try

```
var myNum:Number = 1.123556789
myNum.toFixed(3);
trace(myNum); // 1.123
```

If you need Precision decimal Number try

```
myNum.toPrecision(3);
trace(myNum); // 1.124;
```

For more options see rounding in link.

[Reference NumberFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/NumberFormatter.html#rounding)

Comment: I find this answer really confusing; and I lose you after your comma.  **What** attempts to pass the results of your new function to **what**?  Is the new function a replacement to the function in the original question? Or is it intended to communicate something else?  If you add a little more explanation; I can  remove my downvote.

Comment: Hello Reboog711, the idea is that with this function (which I use for rounding) complete "their" function. ADDING the finish line and the number of decimal places to round.
Likewise, you can reuse that function I mention him for NUMBERS, that was the intention simply.
Thanks, your vote just does not bother me, if you think the answer is not useful, I feel good that you give negative feedback.
regards
Sorry for my English Google, do not speak fluent English.

Comment: Please edit your question to add some of the clarification you gave in the comment.

Comment: I did it after you placed the comment.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I think I may have put too much in the question. The problem is that "value * scale" seems to introduce an error which cannot be simply rounded. In this example, the value = 76.7549, scale = 10000 should return 76.7549 with the ceiling function. But something like value = 76.754900123, scale = 10000 should return 76.7550. I do not see how  to use the roundToPrecision to resolve this issue. I have another example where "22252 - 22252.03" gives -0.029999999998835847 instead of -0.3. This should be simple math without such errors.